# Android OTA update: setting file permissions

Tags: android, embedded, ota

While working on embedded Android 4.3 Jelly Bean: I am trying to install executable files in odd places, i.e. not in /system/bin. This builds fine and produces executable files in the right place. However, when downloaded as OTA they do not have execute permissions any longer.

I use LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := EXECUTABLES and control file placement via LOCAL_MODULE_PATH during build.

How do I keep the executable permissions?